# Requirements for AI to be able to read a book and accurately recall the facts?

Tags: large-language-models, knowledge-representation

As a fun random project I've been working on is learning languages and making cheatsheets for them, dictionaries, etc.. I would love to encode the grammar rules which have been captured in books written in natural language (with some tables and diagrams in the books), across many different languages and writing systems. It is very tedious and time consuming to go into a book written by some grammar master, learn and grok each grammar rule well enough to turn it into structured JSON-like data, and then capture each one like that.

[The Astadhyayi of Panini](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8171105890) is over 1500+ pages (in translation), which is a Sanskrit grammar. I met someone who said they've spent the past few years converting that Sanskrit grammar into code (maybe 3-5 years), and they are only a fraction of the way through. Multiply this by 100-1000+ languages and you are going to be in for a thousand+ human years to capture the grammar data into structured form.

What is required for AI to be able to solve this problem: read a book (PDF or otherwise), learn the material just in that one book, well enough to abstract out each casually defined grammar rule into structured JSON? Are LLMs even close to being able to do this? Predicting next token seems a far cry from being able to represent and learn explicit knowledge like this. But I don't have enough intuition for determining how far AI is from doing this. Where are we at, and what are the unsolved problems or missing pieces we must address before getting to this level?

*As a sidenote, my experience with ChatGPT trying to have it teach me about languages, is it gets 90% of the specific facts wrong, either entirely wrong or slightly wrong. Maybe it's just me. But maybe we need a different approach to reading a book and recalling the facts. I would just like to know at a high level what that might look like, if we have any sense yet.*

*Side-side note: I write this after seeing so many startups subsumed by OpenAI's latest release, and I'm wondering if I should even spend any time on my task or just wait it out haha, wait for AI to be able to solve it. I am not making a startup, just trying to learn several languages, but still.*